# In the Linux kernel (module programming) how to get threadids from a multithreaded process?

Tags: c, kernel

current->pid gets the process id accessing the module...but I want the threadid from the process in a multithreaded program accessing my module. What is the call to do this? I can't find it anywhere!

Comment: what multithreaded library are you using?

Comment: None - I am doing modular programming - no multithreading library is available at that level AFAIK - just clone() and other system calls. current refers to the task_struct accessing the module, but all task_struct has is a pid. The user space program is using openMP...but that shouldn't matter as my module should be user-code agnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linux kernel does not see multithreaded processes in the same way as the POSIX thread library (which I assume is what you mean by thread id). The kernel has tasks which are somewhat separate processes looped together by the thread library. This [paper](http://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2002/ols2002-pages-330-337.pdf) from IBM gives a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Ahhh...so these tasks...it is safe to say they have a pid and I can use that as a "thread id". Thanks!